# After rotate image shows original image instead of rotate image

Tags: jquery, image, rotation

I want to show rotate image after click on left and right button
But is shows original image and after clearing history and cache it will show rotate image

```
    var degrees = 0;
            $("#cboxRight").on('click', function () {
                var $cboxphoto = $('.cboxPhoto');
                degrees += 90;
                $cboxphoto.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
                $cboxphoto.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
                $cboxphoto.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
                $cboxphoto.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
                $cboxphoto.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
saveRotateImage(this.id, tr_job_room_id, new_path_colorbox);
            });

            $("#cboxLeft").on('click', function () {
                var $cboxphoto = $('.cboxPhoto');
                degrees -= 90;
                $cboxphoto.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
                $cboxphoto.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
                $cboxphoto.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
                $cboxphoto.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
                $cboxphoto.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
saveRotateImage(this.id, tr_job_room_id, new_path_colorbox);
            });
    function saveRotateImage(cboxid, ids, path) {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("saveRotateImage")',
            dataType: "json",
            mtype: "post",
            data: { cbox_id: cboxid, ids: ids, path: path },
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("Saved");
            }
        });
    }
```

how to show rotate image on click on button

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this..

JS Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/vreverpb/2/

```
$("input[name='toggle']").change(function(){

var degrees = this.value;


        var $cboxphoto = $('.cboxPhoto');
        $cboxphoto.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
        $cboxphoto.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
        $cboxphoto.css('transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
        $cboxphoto.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
        $cboxphoto.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');



    });
```

Comment: Thnx for ur reply ..`cache:false` is working in every browser except IE.. so May b no need of `$("input[name='toggle']")`

Comment: Is the issue with ajax response or image rotation ? Can you explain the issue in detail?

Comment: May b it is problem that IE doesnot respond to `cache:false` http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1849